# ASUS Xtion and Open NI documentation

Tags: openni, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have come across lot of documentation and books on Microsoft Kinect;

[Beginning Kinect Programming with the Microsoft Kinect SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430241047)

[Meet the Kinect: An Introduction to Programming Natural User Interfaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430238887)

[Hacking the Kinect](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430238674)

However, I have not found much on the ASUS Xtion or on Open NI. Being a Xtion rookie, where should I start ? Any reference to forums, websites, books, tutorials etc would be most useful.

Any first hand experience on how to marry the Xtion (as of now without any robot) with ROS ? Do I have to use OpenNI, or ROS has any way around ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30580/asus-xtion-and-open-ni-documentation/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The power of OpenNI is that it is a "standard" interface to many devices (currently the older Primesense SDK5 devices, Asus XTION and the Kinect). It works just fine with the ROS OpenNI drivers.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2